# When an object is removed from stage, and then added to the stage, do the variables get reset in its class?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

for example

```
    public function RedGoblin() 
    {
        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdd)

    }

    private function onAdd(e:Event):void 
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdd);
        init();

    }

    private function init():void 
    {
        goblinLife = 4;
        trace("init");
    }
```

When an instance of this is added to the stage, it will have four lives.

Now lets says the lives were 0 and this had been removed.

Then you decide to add the instance to the stage

```
addChild(enemy) //(is data type to RedGoblin)
```

So in theory, it's life should be 4 right? Or will it be 0?

Because in my game, it's not setting the life back to 4 I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing from the stage doesn't destroy the instance, so when you come back to the stage (with addChild() ) your old values are intact. But if you re-instantiate then the *initial* values belong to the new instance.

Comment: Perfect! Explains why the variables haven't been reset. I will need to create a reset function then I'm guessing. Or would it be easier to destroy the object completely and have a fresh instance of that object? 

May I please have your expertise?

Comment: Depends on the use case. It's good to avoid needlessly creating new objects, especially if you have a large number of them. Look up object pooling